# golang println and log do not produce output in terminal

Tags: go, logging, println

I am developing a project in Go. I frequently make calls to `fmt.Println` and `log.Output` to keep track of what is happening in my code. However, sometimes, the output from both of these does not appear in the output.

Here is an example of code in which this fault appears persistently.

```
func ClientLoginRequest(ctx *gin.Context) {
    // ...
    body, _ := auth.ProtectedResourceServerRequest(username, " get user details ", "/user") 
    jsonErr := json.Unmarshal(body, &models.UserServerItem)
    if jsonErr != nil {
        log.Output(1, "Failed to obtain user details")
    } else {
        log.Output(1, fmt.Sprintf("Setting current simulation to be %d", models.UserServerItem.CurrentSimulation))
        models.Users[username].CurrentSimulation = models.UserServerItem.CurrentSimulation
    }
    ctx.Redirect(http.StatusFound, "/user/dashboard")
}
```

The behavior is the same if the calls to `log.Output` are replaced by calls to `fmt.Println`.

There is no path that does not request the project to produce output. But no output occurs.

What should I do to ensure that the output of such statements appears in my terminal?

Comment: The problem goes away if the ctx.redirect is removed. But I would still like to know why it occurs

Comment: Insufficient information. One common source for this type of problem is stdout being redirected. Either explicitly or because somewhere in your code you closed file-descriptor one and a subsequent open allocated that file-descriptor to a different destination than your terminal. Removing the `ctx` variable means you also removed the `ctx.Redirect(...)` call. That is a very radical change that also modifies the behavior of your program but I don't see how that would affect the `log.Output(...)` calls. So you are clearly not telling us the whole story.

Comment: The problem with 'insufficient information' is that it's hard to determine what information could help. I could supply the whole programme, but this obliges responders to plough through it all. So I want to see if I can pin down exactly what the cause might be without overloading responders.

The ctx variable is always present. Of course, removing it would indeed be radical and the function would no longer serve the purpose for which it is intended, namely to handle login requests.

What I said above is that the problem disappears if the ctx.Redirect call is removed.

Comment: I'm hoping to get responses from others who have encountered the same or similar problems. I rummaged around in previous answers, and I do recall at one point discovering a related question, but sadly failed to take note of it

Comment: By the way, since I'm currently in England, I spell behaviour with the u in it.

Comment: Try some things: 1. have a look to "logrus" librairie | 2. try using `fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "")`. From there should I have some ideas

Comment: If your program runs long enough run `lsof` against the PID. Verify that FD 1 and 2 are open on your tty. If they're open on something else, or closed, that may provide a useful clue.

Comment: Thanks @J-JacquesM and @Kurtis Rader I will try both those things. I will also see if I can isolate the problem with some kind of example mini-project. I run against the same issue in another part of my code which also had a call to ```ctx.Redirect``` so I suspect this is what is causing the problem